# Select Dropdown is going off screen for long option values

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using just HTML and CSS and Bootstrap. I have very long values in options but I want them would be displayed in s `col-md-6` select box. But the select box is coming in proper way but values are going off screen. For desktop and tablet also.

I searched a lot but not got proper solution for this.

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    select {
      width: 400px; 
      font-size: xx-large; 
    }

    option {
      font-size: xx-large;
      padding: .5em; 
    }
  </style>

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="id_foo">Foo:</label> 
    <select name="foo" id="id_foo" style="width:100%">
       <option>1dfdsfsdfdsfdfdsfdfdsfddgfgghghghghjhgjhgghkhjkhgkjkeretryw4562456fhgfh</option>
       <option>2</option>
       <option>3</option>
       <option>4</option>
       <option>5</option>
       <option>6</option>
       <option>7</option>
       <option>8</option>
       <option>9</option>
    </select><br />
</div>
</div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can add css property to show ellipsis on overflow. You can look into word-wrap as  well but since your option text is 1 long word, it will not work. You can use this as reference: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Comment: works good on desktop, but i want it  responsive for tablets and desktop.

Comment: its not working for long sentence also.

Answer (score 0):

I Found answer.

Its Bootstrap Col-md-x class issue. from my starting container , i misspalced some class values. now i reaarranged them its coming exactly how i want. Thanks Rajesh.